# Mozart K545 Bar 36, Bass clef, last G, natural or sharp?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, mozart, sonata, editions

Mozart's sonata **K545**, **Bar 36, bass clef**, the urtext edition from sheetmusic2print shows a **natural sign ♮** in front of the **F** rather than its preceding **G** (see picture, in red circle), why would the **F** need the natural sign? On the other hand, the edition I got from free-scores has the **natural sign ♮** in front of the **G** that precedes the **F** (see arrows in the red circle), which would make sense since the previous two **G**'s have **#**. HOWEVER, in all the videos I've seen on youtube, the performers played that as **G#**.

So, if the urtext from sheetmusic2print is correct, why the need for **natural sign ♮** for the **F**? Or could it be a printing error and should belong to the preceding **G**? Anyone has a trusted urtext edition not from sheetmusic2print to verify? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The natural sign before the F is a "courtesy accidental". Because of the F# in the right hand's ascending scale on beats 1 and 2, the natural sign in question is included to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the right hand is a concern... So my free-scores edition has yet another mistake! Glad I have asked, or I'd have continued playing the wrong note.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the right-hand is not a concern. Accidentals only apply to the specific staff line/space they appear on. However, to be on the safe side, many editions will include the courtesy accidental. BTW, sites like free-scores are notoriously unreliable. For things like Mozart, you're generally much better off with a site like [IMSLP](https://www.imslp.org), where you can also download for free.

Comment: Thanks. I chose the free-scores because it has fingering and also more readable print (many on IMSLP are scanned copies, not very readable). I think after getting familiar with the fingering I'll use a reliable edition. P.S. in my free-score edition, some parts have an octave higher than it should be, some have an octave lower!

Comment: It's very unusual to see courtesy accidentals that 'correct' changed notes from other octaves - and other staves. Players at that level shouldn't need them anyway. Instead of helping, it's confused at least one - the OP!

Comment: @Tim, isn't the Urtext edition supposed to be written completely by Mozart himself, including the courtesy parts?

Comment: Just checked Henle Urtext. The "courtesy accidental" is there, so presumably Mozart's notation. Speculation: the rule wasn't codified at that point in time.